# Parsing a string inside a vector c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file:

```
bob,10,20,30
joe,50,60,50
shelly,20,15,29
```

that I want to read into a vector of type student, defined:

```
   class student
    {

      public:
        string name;
        int exam1;
        int exam2;
        int exam3;

            student (string s, int x, int y, int z)
            {
              name = s;
              exam1 = x;
              exam2 = y;
              exam3 = z;
            }
    };
```

Using iterators begin() and end(), I am able to store the strings, line by line, but I want to be able to parse these strings to store a students name and his/her exam scores, but I don't know it can be done.

I read about 'find' and 'substr' from the string class but I'm a bit new to iterators and vectors in general. How can I parse the vector using 'find' and 'substr' when it is of type ? I know there may already be many errors in my code or thinking.

main:

```
int main()
{
  //Open file and create iterator
  ifstream file ("test.txt");
  istream_iterator<string> begin (file), end;

  vector<student> vec (begin, end);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple string parsing with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880903/simple-string-parsing-with-c)

Answer (score 4):

In order to have the standard C++ library parse the strings for you, supply a custom input operator `>>` for the `student` class:

```
istream &operator >>( istream &input, student &res ) {
    string s;
    int x, y, z;
    char comma; // Ignored
    getline(input, s, ',');
    input >> comma >> x >> comma >> y >> comma >> z;
    res = student(s, x, y, z);
    return input;
}
```

This implementation is less efficient than it could be, because it requires copying. You could make it more efficient by writing directly into the fields of `student`, because they are public:

```
istream &operator >>( istream &input, student &res ) {
    getline(input, res.name, ',');
    char comma; // Ignored
    input >> comma >> res.exam1 >> comma >> res.exam2 >> comma >> res.exam3;
    return input;
}
```

Finally, you could make the fields private, and declare the `operator >>` a `friend` of the `student` class.

Comment: When I try your second example, I get the error  'std::istream& student::operator>>(std::istream&, student&)' must take exactly one argument

Comment: @filposs I think this is because you declared the operator inside the class without making it a `friend` of the class. Once you mark it as `friend`, it becomes non-member, and is allowed to take the second parameter. See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3312269/335858) for information.